# Как заставить валидировать все данные <v-data-table>?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Необходимо по нажатию кнопки `Save` сделать так, чтобы валидация сработала по всем данным таблицы.

Если отрендерены ошибочные данные, т.е. отображена страница таблицы, где есть не выполнение правил (`rules`), то валидация отработает корректно и результат функции `Save` будет — `invalid`, а если не корректные данные располагаются на не отображенных страницах, то валидация будет пройдена.

Демонстрация проблемы:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      valid: true,
      headers: [
        {         
          text: 'Еденица',
          align: 'center',
          value: 'name'
        },
        {         
          text: 'Значение',
          align: 'center',
          value: 'value'
        },
        {         
          text: 'Приоритет',
          align: 'center',
          value: 'val'
        },
      ],
      items: [
        {
          name: 'Вес',
          value: 408,
          val: 10,
        },
        {
          name: 'Вес',
          value: 408,
          val: 10,
        },
        {
          name: 'Вес',
          value: 408,
          val: 10,
        },
        {
          name: 'Вес',
          value: 1408,
          val: 110,
        },
        {
          name: 'Вес',
          value: 408,
          val: 10,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ruleValue(val){
      return val < 1000 || 'Много';
    },
    ruleVal(val){
      return val < 100 || 'Много Val';
    },
    save(){
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        console.info('Valid');
      } else {
        console.error('Invalid');
      }
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form
      ref="form"
      v-model="valid"
    >
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        :rows-per-page-items="[2,4,10]"
        pagination.sync
      >
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <tr :class="'test' + props.item.numpos">
            <td>{{props.item.name}}</td>
            <td>
              <v-text-field
                v-model="props.item.value"
                :value="props.item.value"
                :rules="[ruleValue]"
               ></v-text-field>
             </td>
             <td>
              <v-text-field
                v-model="props.item.val"
                :value="props.item.val"
                :rules="[ruleVal]"
               ></v-text-field>
             </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
      <v-btn
        @click="save()"
      >
        Save
      </v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Подскажите как решить данную проблему.

*Решение хотелось (в идеале) бы на версии **Vuetify 1.15.***.*

Comment: По чему не пробежаться по всему массиву? и проверить

Comment: Пожалуйста, продемонстрируйте это, через `rules`.

Comment: @Дмытрык 1. Я не думаю, что это можно назвать багом. 2. Запустите снипет. 3. Затем нажмите кнопку `Save`. 4. Увидите в консоле `valid`, хотя на второй странице данные не удовлетворяющие `rules`.

Comment: Я с Vuetify не работаю, но могу предположить, что валидация проходит, помтому что элементов формы со 2-й страницы еще нет в DOM. Валидировать нечего. Пэтому выхода вижу 2. 1) Валидировать данные вручную 2) Отрисовать скрытую вспомогательную таблицу со всеми данными - и валидировать ее (так при работе с canvas делают)

Comment: @Дмытрык Это уже в идеях. Там всё интереснее. Там вообще рендерится тогда, когда кол-во выводимых данных не равно кол-ву допустимых на странице.